# Метод try с ресурсами

Tags: java, try

Задача -
Создайте статический класс Car, чтобы объекты этого типа можно было использовать в try-with-resources.

Метод close() должен выводить на экран фразу "Машина закрывается...".

Try должен ловить все непроверяемые исключения и игнорировать их.

В методе main в блоке try вызови метод drive(). Метод drive должен выводить на экран сообщение "Машина поехала."

Требования:

1. Решение должно содержать статический класс Car.
2. Решение должно содержать метод main.
3. В решение должен использоваться try с ресурсами.

Вопрос в коде
Выкидывает ошибку - "Ошибка в сигнатуре метода drive внутри конструкции try-with-resources"

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Car car = new Car()) {
        drive();
    } catch (RuntimeException ignore) {
    }
}

private static void drive() {
    System.out.println("Машина поехала.");
}

public static class Car implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Машина закрывается...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема [НЕ воспроизводится](https://ideone.com/9ApeQa)

Answer (score 0):

я просто создал класс Controller дабавил код в этот класс и вот что выводит

```
public class Controller {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Car car = new Car()) {
        drive();
    } catch (RuntimeException ignore) {
    }
}

private static void drive() {
    System.out.println("Машина поехала.");
}

public static class Car implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Машина закрывается...");
    }
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И чем этот ответ отличается по сути от комментария со [ссылкой на пример кода](https://ideone.com/9ApeQa)?  Проблема автора вопроса не воспроизводится.